# NuxtJs Axios rendering issue undifined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

When I try to access certain objects/property loaded from an axios call inside the document,

I get undefined property, even though that the master object is being rendered just fine.

Here is what I have tried:
**index.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ pageContent.Cover.formats.large.url}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                baseUrl: process.env.API_URL,
                pageContent: '',
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.$axios.$get(process.env.API_URL + '/about')
                .then(response => (this.pageContent = response))
        }
    }
</script>
```

This gives me following error:

> TypeError
> Cannot read property 'formats' of undefined

This is the object:

[image]

Comment: adds one console.log to check what is the response of axios.get, then you will find the issue. like `console.log(response);console.log(response.data);`

Comment: logging the console.log(response) outputs the exact object like you se above =). Thoguh I can't reference {{ pageContent.Cover.formats.large.url}} even though its showing in the log object

Answer (score 1):

The callback `response` parameter often comes with multiple fields like `data` so you should do :

```
.then(response => (this.pageContent = response.data))
```

then in the template add a conditional rendering :

```
<div v-if="pageContent">
        {{ pageContent.Cover.formats.large.url}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Not in this case, the response is just the object data itself. It does not work with your example. My point was that I can do like: {{pageContent.Cover}} and the Cover properties will be displayed nicely along with cover.formats.large.url, though if I do {{ pageContent.Cover.formats.large.url}} I get undefined. :/

Comment: what about initializing `pageContent` as an empty object `pageContent: {}`

Comment: Hmm… unfortunately still the same, undefined. This is the object which gets printed when I do {{pageContent.Cover}} just so you can see it as a reference: https://imgur.com/a/lNZnLcK. Just for some reason can’t access {{pageContent.Cover.formats.large.url}}

Comment: what about `{{  pageContent.Cover && pageContent.Cover.formats.large.url}}` or `<div v-if="pageContent.Cover">
        {{ pageContent.Cover.formats.large.url}}
    </div>`